# CUDA error: too much shared data (0x4018 bytes, 0x4000 max): where do the extra 0x18bytes come from?

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda, size, gpu-shared-memory

I am trying to implement this CUDA example:
http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/
Because I have 0x4000 bytes available, I tried to use `TILE_DIM = 128`, so that

```
__shared__ unsigned char tile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM];
```

would be of size 0x4000 bytes = 16384 bytes = 128*128 bytes.

However, this gives me the following error:

```
CUDACOMPILE : ptxas error : Entry function '_Z18transposeCoalescedPh' uses too much shared data (0x4018 bytes, 0x4000 max)
```

So I have 0x18 (24) extra bytes in shared memory. Where do they come from, and is it possible to remove them?

I could compile for Compute version 2.0+ higher to remove the error (my hardware is version 3.0), but that would use memory from the L1 cache which is supposedly slower.

Comment: Is this only happening when compiling for sm_1x architectures?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this: "I could compile for Compute version 2.0+ higher to remove the error (my hardware is version 3.0), **but that would use memory from the L1 cache**."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I have 0x18 (24) extra bytes in shared memory. Where do they come from, and is it possible to remove them?

Referring to the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multiprocessor-level):

> The total amount of shared memory required for a block is equal to the sum of the amount of statically allocated shared memory, the amount of dynamically allocated shared memory, **and for devices of compute capability 1.x, the amount of shared memory used to pass the kernel's arguments** (see `__noinline__` and `__forceinline__`).

As long as you compile for a cc1.x architecture, you won't be able to elminate the use of shared memory to carry kernel parameters.

I think the solution as you've already indicated, is to compile for a cc2.0 or cc3.0 architecture.  It's not clear why you wouldn't want to do this.

Comment: Thanks.
I'll have to see how allowing the L1 cache size to be reduced plays with performance in my case.

Comment: If you compile for cc2.0 or higher, the parameters should be passed through the constant memory system, and should not impact the shared memory usage.

Comment: Just encounter similar behaviour on nVidia OpenCL, except that only 4 bytes were missing.